# Brazil transit visa required for Indian citizens?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, connecting-flights, brazil

I am an Indian citizen and I’m planning to visit Dominican Republic. My flights are from Ahmedabad to Dubai, then Dubai to Sao Paulo, then Sao Paulo to Panama City, and then Panama to Santo Domingo.

From Ahmedabad to Sao Paulo my airline carrier would be Emirates, and I have stopover in Brazil of 8.48 hours. Then I have my next flight to Panama with Copa Airlines.

Do I need Transit Visa for Brazil?

Comment: Is this booked as a single ticket (one PNR) or a self-transfer? Will you have checked luggage?

Comment: No I didn’t book a ticket but i have to provide it for my visa Application and embassy requires it. And yes this is a single pnr ticket

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a self-connection, I don’t think you need a transit visa for Brazil.  According to [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm)

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers with a connecting flight booked on the same ticket in transit.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply at Curitiba (CWB), Florianopolis (FLN), Porto Alegre (POA), Porto Seguro (BPS) or Salvador (SSA).

Comment: But the airline company doesn’t mention that this is self transfer or not it says only connection in Sao Paulo of 8 hours 43 minutes

Comment: @ShivamPatel You said in a comment that the itinerary is under one PNR (one ticket covering A>B>C>D>E). Self-transfer means that, instead of having a ticket from A to E via B, C, and D, you have separate tickets, one from A to B, and one from A to C etc. Your baggage won't be transferred, you will need to go landside and back airside to collect and re-check it. If you’re not sure what booking type you have, ask the booking agent and/or call the airline(s) to confirm.

Comment: No it’s a one single ticket with Emirates and Copa Airline