# Does someone need a transit visa in São Paulo Brazil when having a connecting flight with a different airline but on the same ticket?

Tags: transit, gru, ugandan-citizens

I have a Ugandan client who arrives in São Paulo on South African Airlines and after 12 hours of layover, she is supposed to depart with Copa Airlines to Panama City. Would she need a transit visa in São Paulo in Brazil?

Comment: [Here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182891/brazil-transit-visa-required-for-indian-citizens?rq=1) is a related question. It is not a duplicate as the earlier question concerned a citizen of India, not Uganda.

Answer (score 3):

**If** those are separate tickets, your client will need to go landside to check in to next flight. Because of that, he/she will need to leave airside and enter Brazil, requiring a visa to do so. Brazil does not have transit visas, so the one they will need to apply for is a regular visitor visa.

**If** the whole trip is a single ticket (PNR), then no visa is necessary because Brazil does not require visas for any nationality if you stay airside.

Answer (score 0):

In Brazil, visas are [not required for airport transit](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=ug&destination=pa&transit=br) in São Paulo, from any nationality, as long as the traveler does not leave the international transit area.